# Is Service Locator a good pattern for a framework?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, service-locator

I'm building a GUI framework and I currently have a lot of lines like (usually in the constructor)

```
var renderer = locator.GetService<IRenderer>();
var input = locator.GetService<IMouseInput>();
```

Those services I'm getting are core services, I mean, services that are inherently part of what is considered *the basics*.

I have thought about using constructor injection, but some annoyances arise.

- I will have to modify almost every constructor to have its dependencies injected, and that means it will receive even the most basic "services". I'm afraid of having 3 or 4 arguments in each constructor.
- But another thing that is even worse is that end users of the framework won't be happy if they don't find **parameterless constructors**. Do you imagine that creating a TextBox required you to pass all the dependencies it really needs?

The end user could be overwhelmed with `new TextBox(dep1, dep2, dep3)`.

So, is there a good way to remove the Service Locator completely without making it too complex?

**EDIT**

In the team we are discussing and they still WANT to keep the Service Locator arguing the following. This is a fragment of the conversation:

> We don't care about single resposibility in TextBox implementation. We
>   arent' writing an application. It's a UI framework! It's supposed to
>   *hide* stuff and details from end user, not to expose them. A fluent builder for a TextBox? Seriously? We aren't writing some web request
>   handling pipeline.
>
> I agree with all what he *(Stack Overflow users)* wrote, but regarding
>   *applications*. Where you want stuff to be as extensible and reusable as possible. We have like 10 services. They are used *everywhere*. If
>   we had like 50 dependencies with complex object graphs, we couldn't do
>   anything without DI and stuff. The thing about DI is that you have pay
>   for it. So for us Service Locator is free DI isn't It would be just
>   unmaintainable- By having more complex API, by having backward API/ABI
>   compatibility, etc. We are paying for Service Locator by not knowing
>   what class needs as its dependencies and some problems with providing
>   different dependency implementations for different instances. But we
>   don't need either, so Service Locator is free. DI isn't.

Do you agree? Why?

Comment: What is an `IRenderer` and why is it an interface? What is its lifetime? As a framework, I would actually think that you'd want to avoid bringing in an IOC framework. From a performance point of view, you really should be hard coding everything in the constructor.

Comment: So what's wrong with current locator approach, assuming you that locator is global object?

Comment: The locator is wrong because it's hiding the dependencies, that is a bad thing.

Comment: @Aron the lifetime of the objects are basically from the start of the application to its end. It's only one instance of each of them. It's an interface because it will be cross-platform and it needs to have different implementations.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with the constructor injection approach when you pass all the dependencies in the constructor — it is much better than resolving them with the service locator, which is, essentially, an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

With constructor injection, your APIs does not lie about their dependencies and make them obvious.

Comment: I agree with not wanting to have x params in a ctor. But I also do not get the big Idea behind a DI-container here. Wouldn't it be good enough to have a static object (that can be replaced for test) where everyone depends on. It contains all Renderers, FontResources and what not is needd. .... for performance reasons (since life span is whole time)

Answer (score 2):

> I will have to modify almost every constructor to have its dependencies injected, and that means it will receive even the most basic "services". I'm afraid of having 4 or 5 arguments in each constructor.

If you have 4 or 5 services in a constructor, it is an indication you are violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). At that point it is time to refactor to an [Aggregate Service (otherwise known as a facade service)](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

> But another thing that is even worse is that end users of the framework will not have parameterless constructors. Do you imagine that creating a TextBox required you you pass all the dependencies it really needs?

Well, first of all it should be clear whether you are designing a *framework* or in fact that it is a *library*.

But either way, you should make it possible to inject services for overriding, but provide logical default behaviors. The best way to achieve that is by using a fluent builder to compose your services. That is, the public API will be comprised of builders that will do all of the configuration of the underlying services. You can then expose overloads that allow injection of custom services as required by the end user (i.e. one overload to build a default set of services with a builder, and one overload that just accepts the abstraction).

Here is a quick example that shows how that can be done:

```
public class VideoContentBuilder : IVideoContentBuilder
{
    private readonly string thumbnailLocation;
    private readonly string title;
    private readonly ICompressor compressor;

    public VideoContentBuilder()
        // Supply logical defaults
        : this(
            thumbnailLocation: string.Empty,
            title: string.Empty,
            compressor: new DefaultVideoCompressor(new Dependency())
        )
    {}

    private VideoContentBuilder(
        string thumbnailLocation,
        string title,
        ICompressor compressor)
    {
        this.thumbnailLocation = thumbnailLocation;
        this.title = title;
        this.compressor = compressor;
    }

    public IVideoContentBuilder WithThumbnailLocation(string thumbnailLocation)
    {
        return new VideoContentBuilder(thumbnailLocation, this.title, this.compressor);
    }

    public IVideoContentBuilder WithTitle(string title)
    {
        return new VideoContentBuilder(this.thumbnailLocation, title, this.compressor);
    }

    // Use a builder to configure defualt services
    //
    // Syntax:
    // .WithCompressor(compressor => compressor.WithLevel(Level.Maximum).WithEncryption(Encryption.None))
    public IVideoContentBuilder WithCompressor(Func<ICompressorBuilder, ICompressorBuilder> expression)
    {
        var starter = new CompressorBuilder(this.compressor);
        var builder = expression(starter);
        var compressor = builder.Create();

        return new VideoContentBuilder(this.thumbnailLocation, this.title, compressor);
    }

    // Allow a custom compressor to be injected.
    //
    // Syntax:
    // .WithCompressor(new CustomCompressor())
    public IVideoContentBuilder WithCompressor(ICompressor compressor)
    {
        return new VideoContentBuilder(this.thumbnailLocation, this.title, compressor);
    }

    // Create the configured service.
    public IVideoContent Create()
    {
        return new VideoContent(this.thumbnailLocation, this.title, compressor);
    }
)
```

### Usage

```
var videoContentBuilder = new VideoContentBuilder()
    .WithThumbnailLocation("http://www.example.com/thumb.jpg")
    .WithTitle("The greatest video")
    .WithCompressor(compressor => compressor
        .WithQuality(Level.High)
        .WithAlgorithm(Algorithm.ReallyCool)
        .WithDependentService(new DependentService())
    );

var videoContent = videoContentBuilder.Create();
```

References:

- http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/
- http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/

Comment: Do you think the same suggestions applies to A FRAMEWORK? Internally, we have people arguing that (please, see the edited question)

Comment: Of course. A framework should not include DI, only provide support for it. But whether you take the builder idea (which is obviously more complex) or simply use multiple constructor overloads as in the article I linked to is up to you. You can easily hide the builder behind a static member or other facade so the user doesn't have to new it up. Do note that several modern UI frameworks use the Builder approach (such as [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation)). It is quicker for end users to deal with than looking for the right constructor or method overload.

Comment: Service locator is an option. But it should be considered a last resort, after all other possibilities have been exhausted. It may be the best option for your team, but it may not be the best option for your users. But it really depends on how often you expect users to customize your implementation. If 1% of them will need customization support then you might be better off with a service locator and some documentation to tell what types can be customized. If 25% of your users require customization support, you should take the builder approach more seriously.

Comment: It also depends on whether you are building a custom UI framework or just a sub-framework of an existing UI framework such as WPF. It is far easier to support the builder approach in a DI friendly environment such as WPF or MVC than with a legacy framework such as Windows Forms or Web Forms.